# I need to design a bus timing and route database?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

Each bus comes to a bus stop more than once. There is a route for the bus. It will be returning through the same route.

eg. I am at a stop A. The bus route is from ESU to SYR. I need to search the bus that goes from stop A to SYR after 09 a.m. So while searching I am also getting buses that goes from stop A to ESU also ( i.e the reverse route). How can I manage the same in Database design.

My tables are:

```
Routes ( route_id, route_name).

stops (stop_id, stop_name)

Route_details(route_id, stop_no, stop_id, minutes)   minutes -> time from one stop to other

schedule(route_id, bus, start_time)
```

Is my database design correct? Can anybody please help to sort my problem?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you post some sample data, and the result you're hoping to get?

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: If you are wanting help you need to post what you have tried so far with a little bit of sample data. This seems a lot like a homework question. We wont do the homework for you but can help point you in the reight direction perhaps.

Comment: hello sir, I have developed the db design for the same. And I have a small doubt regarding the forward and reverse direction of bus. If I am not searching based on the time , It will work fine